# D3 Added Circles to a MultiLine Chart - Circles on top of Circles

Tags: d3.js

I'm having an issue where I'm plotting circles on a multi-line chart which has a different color for each line (circles match the colors). The catch is the way I have the function I'm writing circles on top of circles - which is an issue when I try to hide specific ones.

I want to plot circles based on then name but I'm unsure how to limit the above D3 functions to one name only - currently it plots all circles for each line.

Is there a way to use d.name to limit the plotting to one name each time?

thanks

Comment: can you add your code ?

Answer (score 1):

I think [d3.nest](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Arrays.md#nest) is what you want:

```
var names = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d){ return d.name; })
    .entries(data);
```

```js
var data = [
        {"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"20.0","date":"2017-08-25 21:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"93.8","date":"2017-08-25 22:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"86.2","date":"2017-08-25 23:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"79.2","date":"2017-08-26 00:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"81.7","date":"2017-08-26 01:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"76.2","date":"2017-08-26 02:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"86.2","date":"2017-08-26 03:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"89.2","date":"2017-08-26 04:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"91.9","date":"2017-08-26 05:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"78.2","date":"2017-08-26 06:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"86.2","date":"2017-08-26 07:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"82.2","date":"2017-08-26 08:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"96.2","date":"2017-08-26 09:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"88.7","date":"2017-08-26 10:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"92.3","date":"2017-08-26 11:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"80.2","date":"2017-08-26 12:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"76.2","date":"2017-08-26 13:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"93.2","date":"2017-08-26 14:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"89.2","date":"2017-08-26 15:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"79.2","date":"2017-08-26 16:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"90.2","date":"2017-08-26 17:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"85.2","date":"2017-08-26 18:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"86.5","date":"2017-08-26 19:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"76.2","date":"2017-08-26 20:00:00"},{"name":"1.0E-6MHz","value":"94.5","date":"2017-08-26 21:00:00"},
        {"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"26.2","date":"2017-08-25 21:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"33.8","date":"2017-08-25 22:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"26.2","date":"2017-08-25 23:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"66.2","date":"2017-08-26 00:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"3.7","date":"2017-08-26 01:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"76.2","date":"2017-08-26 02:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"36.2","date":"2017-08-26 03:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"22.2","date":"2017-08-26 04:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"31.6","date":"2017-08-26 05:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"44.2","date":"2017-08-26 06:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"7.2","date":"2017-08-26 07:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 08:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 09:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"21.7","date":"2017-08-26 10:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"22.3","date":"2017-08-26 11:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 12:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 13:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 14:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 15:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 16:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"96.2","date":"2017-08-26 17:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 18:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"33.5","date":"2017-08-26 19:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 20:00:00"},{"name":"2.0E-6MHz","value":"44.5","date":"2017-08-26 21:00:00"},
        {"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"38.2","date":"2017-08-25 21:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"43.8","date":"2017-08-25 22:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"56.2","date":"2017-08-25 23:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 00:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"53.7","date":"2017-08-26 01:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"3.2","date":"2017-08-26 02:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 03:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"66.2","date":"2017-08-26 04:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"37.9","date":"2017-08-26 05:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"42.2","date":"2017-08-26 06:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"4.2","date":"2017-08-26 07:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 08:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 09:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"21.7","date":"2017-08-26 10:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"22.3","date":"2017-08-26 11:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 12:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 13:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 14:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 15:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 16:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"96.2","date":"2017-08-26 17:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 18:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"33.5","date":"2017-08-26 19:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 20:00:00"},{"name":"3.0E-6MHz","value":"34.5","date":"2017-08-26 21:00:00"},
        {"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-25 21:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"53.8","date":"2017-08-25 22:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"86.2","date":"2017-08-25 23:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"56.2","date":"2017-08-26 00:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"23.7","date":"2017-08-26 01:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"16.2","date":"2017-08-26 02:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"76.2","date":"2017-08-26 03:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"82.2","date":"2017-08-26 04:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"39.9","date":"2017-08-26 05:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"6.2","date":"2017-08-26 06:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"22.2","date":"2017-08-26 07:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 08:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 09:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"21.7","date":"2017-08-26 10:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"22.3","date":"2017-08-26 11:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 12:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 13:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 14:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 15:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 16:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"96.2","date":"2017-08-26 17:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 18:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"33.5","date":"2017-08-26 19:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 20:00:00"},{"name":"4.0E-6MHz","value":"24.5","date":"2017-08-26 21:00:00"},
        {"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"66.2","date":"2017-08-25 21:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"63.8","date":"2017-08-25 22:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"16.2","date":"2017-08-25 23:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"86.2","date":"2017-08-26 00:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"13.7","date":"2017-08-26 01:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"36.2","date":"2017-08-26 02:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"6.2","date":"2017-08-26 03:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"21.2","date":"2017-08-26 04:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"41.1","date":"2017-08-26 05:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"86.2","date":"2017-08-26 06:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"69.2","date":"2017-08-26 07:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 08:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 09:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"21.7","date":"2017-08-26 10:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"22.3","date":"2017-08-26 11:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 12:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 13:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 14:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 15:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 16:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"96.2","date":"2017-08-26 17:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 18:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"33.5","date":"2017-08-26 19:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"46.2","date":"2017-08-26 20:00:00"},{"name":"5.0E-6MHz","value":"4.5","date":"2017-08-26 21:00:00"}
    ];

// parsing 
data.forEach(function(d){
    d.value = +d.value;
    d.date = new Date(d.date);
})


// after this you will have 5 name keys of its values(in your case)
var names = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d){ return d.name; })
        .entries(data);


// console.log(names)

var chart = d3.select("#chart");
d3.select("#names")
    .selectAll("button")
    .data(names.map(function(d){ return d.key; }))
    .enter()
    .append("button")
    .text(function(d){ return d; })
    .on("click", redraw);

var svgWidth = 500,
    svgHeight = 400,
    radius = 5,
    margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30 },
    width = svgWidth - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, height]),
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient("bottom").scale(xScale),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient("left");

var svg = chart.append("svg").attr({ width: svgWidth, height: svgHeight });
var gMain = svg.append("g").attr({
        class: "gMain",
        transform: "translate(" + [margin.left, margin.top] + ")"
    }),
    gYAxis = gMain.append("g").attr("class", "axis yaxis"),
    gXAxis = gMain.append("g").attr({
        class: "axis xaxis",
        transform: "translate(0," + height + ")"
    })
    gPlot = gMain.append("g").attr({
        class: "plot",
        transform: "translate(0," + height + ")"
    });


redraw("1.0E-6MHz", 0);


function redraw(name, index){
    var points = names[index].values;
    
    xScale.domain(d3.extent(points, function(d){ return d.date; }));
    yScale.domain(d3.extent(points, function(d){ return d.value; }));

    gXAxis.transition().call(xAxis);
    gYAxis.transition().call(yAxis.scale(yScale.copy().range([height, 0])));
    
    var update = gPlot.selectAll("circle").data(points),
        enter = update.enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr({
                    class: "circle",
                    r: radius,
                    fill: "steelblue",
                    cx: function(d){ return xScale(d.date); },
                    cy: function(d){ return -yScale(d.value); }
                });
    update.exit().remove();
    update.transition()
        .duration(700)
        .attr({
            cx: function(d){ return xScale(d.date); },
            cy: function(d){ return -yScale(d.value); }
        });

}
```

```css
.axis path{
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1;
}
.axis line{
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>


<div id="names"></div>
<div id="chart"></div>
```